# How to use Gradio interface to auto submit the audio when recording is done?

Tags: python, gradio

I am using the following Gradio sample code to transcribe my audio:

```
from transformers import pipeline
p = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition")

import gradio as gr

def transcribe(audio):
    text = p(audio)["text"]
    return text

gr.Interface(
    fn=transcribe, 
    inputs=gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath"), 
    outputs="text").launch()
```

However, the user has to start recording audio, stop recording audio, and the submit the audio. Can I auto submit the audio when the user presses stop recording audio?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. I am putting it here for other's reference.

```
import gradio as gr

from transformers import pipeline

p = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition")

def transcribe(audio):
    text = p(audio)["text"]
    return text

gr.Interface(
    fn=transcribe, 
    inputs=gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath"), 
    outputs="text",live=True).launch()
```

Adding live=True serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto-submit something like this should work

```
#auto submit after 5 seconds
gr.Interface(
    fn=transcribe,
    inputs=gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath"),
    outputs="text",
    auto_submit=True,
    auto_submit_duration=5).launch()
```